tkinter auto joining thread
I am writing a tkinter app and is using threads for performance (computing-intensive tasks)
Threads need to be joined, but I am lazy.
I don't really like the idea of constantly checking if a thread is alive.
I created a class to handle join automatically when the job is done. However, it still has the risk of having race conditions (that's what GPT said)
class RunInThreadHandler(ctk.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self, master: ctk.CTkBaseClass,
                 target: Callable,
                 args: tuple = (),
                 func_end_callback: Optional[Callable] = None,
                 kwargs: Optional[dict[str, Any]] = None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self._func: Callable = target
        self._args: tuple = args
        self._kwargs: dict[str, Any] = kwargs if kwargs is not None else {}
        self._func_end_callback: Optional[Callable] = func_end_callback
        self._thread: Optional[Thread] = Thread(target=self._thread_func)
        self._thread.start()

    def _thread_func(self):
        try:
            self._func(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
        except BaseException as exc:
            print(exc)
        self.after(1000, self._thread.join)
        if self._func_end_callback is not None:
            self.after(1000, self._func_end_callback)

Usage:
RunInThreadHandler(self, target=foo)  # runs foo in thread on the spot

Q: Any better ways?

You could have a completely separate thread which has a queue on which each instance of RunInThreadHandler inserts itself. That thread blocks on that queue waiting for instances to arrive. When they do it executes instance._thread.join();instance.._func_end_callback().

Typically, the purpose of calling join() is for the creator of the thread to verify that the thread execution has completed or in cases, non-termination, to force terminate the thread and performs the necessary cleanups.
So, if the user of RunInThreadHandler is not interested in waiting for the thread to complete for the reasons above, then I don't see any point in calling join(). Moreover, as you have pointed out yourself, the way you write the code will cause the code to join itself, which will cause your thread to never terminate.

Will this cause system resources to be taken up tho?

As long as the thread terminates, resources will be released regardless of whether the creator of the thread joins it or not. What will cause system resources to be taken up, though, is when a thread tries to join itself, which causes it to never terminate.

Note that self.after(1000, self._thread.join) schedules a call to self._thread.join after 1000 milliseconds from the thread that has .mainloop() or .update(). So the actual call to .join() isn't happening inside the new thread. Therefore, effectively that line just sets up a timer to check if _thread_func will exit in the next second which seems useless to me (if not it stops tkinter from updating util it does).
